# programmatically remove a sub view from it's parent and attaching it to other parent

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, addsubview

I have a UIButton which the user can drag and drop. I recognize the drag and drop with the following method:

```
func addTarget(_ target: AnyObject?,
      action action: Selector, forControlEvents controlEvents: UIControlEvents)
```

In addition, I have a view. Both the view and UIButton are siblings, and are defined in the IB.

My goal is that when the user drags the button into the view, then the button will be disconnected from it's parent, and its new parent will be the view. In other words, the button will be a subview of the view.

What I am doing is (when the button is dragged into the view):

```
button.removeFromSuperview()
view.addSubview(button)
```

This indeed removes the button from it's parent, but still I dont see it inside the view. So, I tried giving the button a red background, and now when the button is dragged to the view, I can see some wierd small red background at the simulator top left corner.

Can someone tell me please what am I doing wrong? Missing somehting?

Comment: did you get an auto layout error in the console?

Comment: You either have to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `true` and then set its `frame`, or you have to set constraints for the button in its new view.

Answer (score 1):

Daniel Rahamim,

I believe the button is getting added  to your view but because button's frame is still pointing to the outer space (beyond child views frame) you cant see it. Try setting the frame and lemme know if you can see it :)

```
button.removeFromSuperview()
button.frame = CGRectMake(view.center.x, view.center.y, button.frame.size.width, button.frame.size.height)
view.addSubview(button)
```

Comment: I will try this when I get back home and let you know. Anyway, I thoght that the button.center is affecting the button.frame, so I don't need to redefine a Rect. (Since when the button moves, I update it's center property)

Comment: @daniel-rahamim : Sure buddy :) If you are using any autolayout constraint constraint might break because you are manually changing frame to some value which might not satisfy the constraint equation :) This answer is just an attempt to tell you havent done anything wrong its just beyond the frame :) if you autolayout constraint rather then setting frame remove the existing constraint and add constraint to your childView :)

Comment: thanks. I am not using any constraints. It's just a simple app in which I am trying to learn things, as I am new to IOS. 
I even tried to use ConvertRect method, but that didn't helped too.
Why updating the button center is not enough? Why I need to update the frame also?

Comment: Nope, that didn't help. Still getting same results as described.
This is what I am doing:
            bt.frame = bt.convertRect(bt.frame, toView: innerView)
            bt.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
            bt.removeFromSuperview()
            innerView.addSubview(bt)

Answer (score 0):

If you change the parent of any object, its frame remain same as it was in its old parent.

So, If the frame of the new parent is different than old parent than you need to set the frame of your object according to the new parent.

To change the parent you can just add the object in to new parent, no need to remove the object from its old parent (object removeFromSuperview), it will manage automatically, because one object can exist at in one parent at the same time.

Comment: If I am deleting the removefromsuperview() line, then for some reason the button returns to it's original place, and yes it is added as a subview. But it doesn't stay inside the inner view.

Answer (score 0):

to remove a button from superview

```
button.removefromsuperview()
```

to add it on a view

```
view.addsubview(button)
```